# How do you attack with the Kraken special?

Tags: splatoon

I recently got the Krak-On Splat Roller which has the Kracken special.

I'd previously been killed by people while they were using the Kraken ability, but I don't seem to be able to damage enemy players with it.

How do you attack with the Kraken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in Kraken form, you can attack other players by jumping (using the X button). If you hit an enemy while you're in the air, you will damage them.

Source: [Splatoon manual](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/ci/fattach/get/131237/1432908508/redirect/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDQzNDQ5NDU3L3NpZC9zWW90YkN4bQ==/filename/manual-nintendo-wiiu-splatoon.pdf), pages 14 and 28

Comment: Related note: a kraken will always spin attack while in the air, even if you didn't jump, so you can kill enemies by falling on them.

Comment: You don't simply "damage them", jumping into an enemy will splat him instantly.